# Capture client-side errors on Sitecore Forms in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-forms, error-handling

We need to capture errors on Sitecore form after Submit button click. Below code return 0 value in console log on first attempt and that might be because errors appear only after submit click. In subsequent click we can see value in console log. One solution is to create a new function, use setTimeout function, set 2-3 seconds delay and write whole logic in new function. Is there any other better approach to capture errors on submit click?

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    console.log($(this).find(".validation-summary-errors .list-group li").length)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore forms uses an unobtrusive form validation library that's dependent on jQuery, to read validation messages, you need to apply the trick prior to DOM ready and certainly NOT in (document).ready.

Please refer to this article to understand unobtrusive validators. here is the [link](https://soyouwannasitecore.wordpress.com/tag/jquery-validate-unobtrusive/)

Comment: Actually that post describes the process for some custom client validation in form and that should be applied on page before DOM ready which is fine but here I think we need to do something after DOM ready because error message only appear after Submit click. For example on page load `.validation-summary-errors` class doesn't exist. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Or might be if there is any option to add a callback function that should trigger after Submit event and we can write logic in callback function